# Find $\lim_{x \to \infty} q (x+1)-q(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ q (x) $ be a differentiable function on $\Bbb R$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} q'(x)=0$. Find $\lim_{x \to \infty} q (x+1)-q(x)$, I think it is zero since by applying the mean value theorem on $[x, x+1$] we get $q (x+1)-q(x)=q'(x+\xi) $ where $0< \xi <1$, then taking the limit as $ x \to \infty$ gives us $\lim_{x \to \infty} q (x+1)-q(x)=0$, is this correct?

Comment: Yes looks good.

Comment: Yep that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a completely valid argument. Cheers :).